# Is there a way to get a list of rendered views in cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I would like to get a list of all view files rendered for a request. Print it our after the sql logs maybe?

Answer (score 1):

If this is for debug purposes, use [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/)

Look under `Timer` and it will show you each view file rendered and how long each took.